# Trying to change code that combines multiple audio files into one to work for more than two files

Tags: java, audio, inputstream

Using jjmpeg, I have this code, which combines two wav files into one:

```
String wavFile1 = "C:/Users/Adela/Desktop/AerLingusPrototype2/src/examples/test.wav";
String wavFile2 = "C:/Users/Adela/Desktop/AerLingusPrototype2/src/examples/test2.wav";

try {
    AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
    AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));

    AudioInputStream appendedFiles =
        new AudioInputStream(
                new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),
                clip1.getFormat(),
                clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

    AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles,
            AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
            new File("C:/Users/Adela/Desktop/AerLingusPrototype2/src/examples/ring3.wav"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So now I have multiple wav files like this, how would I change the code? I have the paths for the file stored as strings in this case

```
AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(startAudio));
AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(flightNumberDigit1Audio));
AudioInputStream clip3 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(flightNumberDigit2Audio));
AudioInputStream clip4 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(flightNumberDigit3Audio));
AudioInputStream clip5 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(departingAtAudio));
AudioInputStream clip6 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(hoursAudio));
AudioInputStream clip7 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(minutesAudio));
AudioInputStream clip8 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(nowClosingAudio));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [`SequenceInputStream` constructor overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#SequenceInputStream(java.util.Enumeration)) that accepts an `Enumeration`.

```
Vector<InputStream> inputStreams = new Vector<InputStream>();
inputStreams.add(clip1);
inputStreams.add(clip2);
inputStreams.add(clip3);
// etc...

// add up the lengths
int length = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < inputStreams.size(); ++i)
    length += inputStreams.get(i).getFrameLength();

AudioInputStream appendedFiles =
    new AudioInputStream(
            new SequenceInputStream(inputStreams.elements()),
            clip1.getFormat(), length);
```